# Can you help me identify this IC?

Tags: digital-logic, power-electronics, identification, electronic-ballast

Can you help me identify what IC is this?

[image]

Context:

[image]

Comment: Good photo. But please add info to your question body about the type of circuit and possibly surrounding components, and how those are connected. Seeing the choke makes me think in the direction of switching regulator, but I see no FET..

Comment: Definitely a buck regulator, in one of the common SOT-23-6 pinouts: 1 = GND, 2 = SW, 3 = VIN, 4 = FB, 5 = EN, 6 = BS. May be a fairly powerful one (2-3A?) given the size of that inductor. I don't find any results offhand from the number, though. Have a sneaking suspicion "2230" is the date code (is this new hardware?), but neither showing much. Would have to flip through datasheets.

Comment: The hand soldering is botched, so in case you think this part is faulty it might as well be the bad solder job on any of those passives. Unfortunately it is also covered by some lacquer... I'd recommend staying under a fume hood while fixing the soldering - otherwise the vapors can be real nasty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to be a [Silicon Content Technology SCT2230](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2008111836_SCT-SCT2230TVBR_C719318.pdf).

Comment: yes, that's probably what it should be
Thank you very much